# Find the length of the red line

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I have been trying to solve this question from twitter for like two days could anyone help me with this?

[image]

All the credits go to the name mentioned in the image

My attempt to solve:

[image]

I think it's harder to understand my messy diagram. But all I have done here is drawing a parallel line from a vertice to the opposite side of the square and with that I have find the lengths of the mentioned segments in terms of x

Thank u in advance for looking into this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop a perpendicular from the center $O$ of the square to the bottom of the square. This creates a right triangle whose hypotenuse is the red segment and which is similar to the right triangle whose hypotenuse is the blue segment. If the square has side length $2x$, and $r$ is the length of the red segment, then by similar triangles you have
$$
\frac r{\sqrt{(2x)^2+1}}\stackrel{(a)}=\frac x{2x}\stackrel{(b)}=\frac{x-2}1
$$
Use equation (b) to solve for $x$. Plug this into equation (a) to obtain $r$.

Answer (score 3):

**HINTS:** Let the side of the square be $2x$. Calculate the slope of the blue line $m_b$, and for the red line $m_r$, in terms of $x$.
Since the lines are perpendicular,
$$m_b\cdot m_r=-1$$
This will allow you to find $x$. Draw the perpendicular from $O$ to the lower horizontal line, then use Pythagoras.